# Converting a table Colum from datetime2 to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, datetime2

I have been assisgned with a starnge assigment where i need to convert 40 tables columns from datetime2 to datetime.

this is the datetime format what i am having in my database.2007-11-12 00:00:00

it contains more than 90,000 records

Please assist

Comment: The format is irrelevent.  Dates are numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You have to check if you have values < January 1, 1753 (because they aren't compatible with `datetime`). For example

> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn < '1753-01-01'

- You have to decide what to do with those values, for example (here I change all the values < 1753-01-01 to 1753-01-01):

> UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = '1753-01-01' WHERE MyColumn < '1753-01-01'

- Modify the type of your column

> ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn DATETIME

Answer (score 3):

that is just rediculos, datetime2 is more exact, it has a bigger daterange and takes up the same number of bytes (8).

here is the code for mssql:

```
alter table tablename alter column colname datetime
```

Comment: If this method does not work for some reason, you can always add a column, update from the old column, drop the old column and rename the new one.

Comment: @DanBracuk old column is datetime2, this will work, although it may lose some precision

Comment: There could be impossible dates: values < January 1, 1753 (the min-date of `datetime`)

Comment: @xanatos well spotted, that would cause out-of-range error and fail

Comment: It will work on those database engines that allow you to directly change a datatype.  I work with one, redbrick, that does not.

Comment: FWIW @t-clausen.dk I am in a situation where clients want to use MS Access to query data out. It doesn't support datetime2 like it does datetime. Sucks, but these situations exist.

Comment: datetime2 cannot handle Select <fieldname> + 1 so it is ridiculous to use it. Who wants to trawl through all their sql to verify that it does not use +1 on a date field. datetime2 is not a replacement for datetime because it does not have the same functionality